# ClassCastException when setting up listener interface

Tags: android, interface, listener, actionlistener

trying to set up a custom listener to send a string from an Activity to a fragment that is inside of that activity.  button on Activity is pressed and the String of text should be sent to the fragment and displayed in the textview of that fragment but I get a classCastException and don't know what to do about this.  how would you get this to work?

the error is on this line

```
 listener = (OnStringRequestedListener) fragment;
```

i don't know how to set up this custom listener interface without that line of code.  i used a similar line of code for going in the opposite direction and it worked. that was or sending a message from fragment to Activity.  however what i am trying today is not working

stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.example.asynctaskprogressbarexample.InterfaceActivityToFragmentFragment
cannot be cast to com.example.asynctaskprogressbarexample
.InterfaceActivityToFragment$OnStringRequestedListener
at com.example.asynctaskprogressbarexample
.InterfaceActivityToFragment.onCreate(InterfaceActivityToFragment.java:27)
```

activity class

```
  public class InterfaceActivityToFragment extends Activity {

Button buttonOne;
private OnStringRequestedListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.interface_activity_to_fragment);

    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

    listener = (OnStringRequestedListener) fragment; // <-- ERROR ON THIS LINE

     if (fragment instanceof OnStringRequestedListener) {
          listener = (OnStringRequestedListener) fragment;
        } else {
          throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString()
              + " must implemenet OnTimeRequestedListener");
        }

    buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              listener.passString("string from Activity");

           }

        });

}

public interface OnStringRequestedListener {
    public void passString(String sendNumberString);

  }

 }
```

fragment class

```
 public class InterfaceActivityToFragmentFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentHeadlessAsyncTaskFragment.OnStringRequestedListener {

TextView textViewOne;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.interface_activity_to_fragment_fragment, container, false);

    TextView textViewOne = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    return view;
} // end on create view

@Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  setRetainInstance(true);
 }

@Override
public void passString(String stringFromActivity) {
     textViewOne.setText(stringFromActivity);

}
  }
```

Comment: Instead of `InterfaceActivityToFragment extends Activity` have you tried extending the class to `FragmentActivity` ? i.e `InterfaceActivityToFragment extends FragmentActivity` ? Also have you tried to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` ? See if it makes any difference?

Comment: have not tried that yet,   i thought that FragmentActivity was for V4 support of older versions of pre api level 11 for use with fragments.  since my target API is 11 and up.  i did not think of using that yet. i will try it now

Comment: actually that is going to be harder than i thought,  i need to change the app and add V4 support in order to use FragmentActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing `FragmentHeadlessAsyncTaskFragment.OnStringRequestedListener` but casting to `InterfaceActivityToFragment.OnStringRequestedListener`.

The same interface defined as nested in two different classes.